# PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored and PL/SQL: ORA-00911: invalid character

Tags: oracle, plsql

The following pl/sql function is used to fetch default values from a table 'TESTER' and return only one NOT NULL value from all 3 different default data types.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE mdvs AS OBJECT
(
l_default_number NUMBER,
l_default_text VARCHAR2(200),
l_default_date DATE
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DEF_VALUE (f_table_name IN VARCHAR2,f_column_name IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN v_mdvs 
IS 
obj_mdvs v_mdvs:=mdvs(0,NULL,NULL);
BEGIN
SELECT Def_NUMBER_Value,Def_TEXT_Value,Def_DATE_Value
INTO obj_mdvs.*,obj_mdvs.*,obj_mdvs.*
FROM    TESTER 
WHERE   Table_Name=f_table_Name
AND     Column_Name=f_column_Name;

IF (l_default_number != 0 ) THEN
obj_mdvs := mdvs(l_default_number);
ELSIF (l_default_text IS NOT NULL) THEN
obj_mdvs := mdvs(l_default_text);
ELSIF (l_default_date IS NOT NULL) THEN
obj_mdvs := mdvs(l_default_date);
ELSE
obj_mdvs :=mdvs('NULL');
END IF;
RETURN obj_mdvs;
END;
```

o/p:
Type MDVS compiled

LINE/COL  ERROR
6/1       PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
7/5       PL/SQL: ORA-00911: invalid
character Errors: check compiler log

not sure how to handle this error.

EDIT:i am facing error in the below code as well . error is mentioned below :

```
    create or replace function defaulttest
        ( f_table_name  in varchar2
        , f_column_name in varchar2 )
        return mdva
    is
        obj_mdva mdva;
    begin
        begin
            select mdva(defaultnumber), mdva(defaulttext), mdva(defaultdate)
            into   obj_mdva
            from   tester
            where  tablename = f_table_name
            and    columnname = f_column_name;
        exception
            when no_data_found then null;
        end;

        return
            case
                when obj_mdva.default_number is not null then
                    mdva(obj_mdva.default_number)
                when obj_mdva.default_text is not null then
                    mdva(obj_mdva.default_text)
                when obj_mdva.default_date is not null then
                    mdva(obj_mdva.default_date)
                else
                    mdva(null)
            end;
    end defaulttest;
```

error:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
PLS-00307: too many declarations of 'MDVA' match this call

code :
create or replace type mdva FORCE as object
( default_number number
, default_text varchar2(200)
, default_date date
, constructor function mdva (num number) return self as result
, constructor function mdva (txt varchar2) return self as result
, constructor function mdva (dt date) return self as result
);
/

```
        create or replace type body mdva as
            constructor function mdva (num number) return self as result 
            is
            begin
                self.default_number := num;
                return;
            end;

            constructor function mdva (txt varchar2) return self as result 
                is
                begin
                    self.default_text:= txt;
                    return;
                end;

                constructor function mdva (dt date) return self as result 
                is
                begin
                    self.default_date := dt;
                    return;
                    end;
            end;

            create or replace function defaulttest
                ( f_table_name  in varchar2
                , f_column_name in varchar2 )
                return mdva
            is
                obj_mdva_number mdva;
                obj_mdva_text   mdva;
                obj_mdva_date   mdva;
            begin
                begin
                    select mdva(t.defaultnumber), mdva(t.defaulttext), mdva(t.defaultdate)
                    into   obj_mdva_number, obj_mdva_text, obj_mdva_date
                    from   tester t
                    where  tablename = f_table_name
                    and    columnname = f_column_name;
                exception
                    when no_data_found then null;
                end;

                return coalesce(mdva_number, mdva.text, obj_mdva_date);
                end defaulttest;
                
                select defaulttest('table','field') from dual;
```

o/p:
Defaulttest('table','field')
SDPSGT.MDVA(4, NULL, NULL)

SQLQUERY:
SELECT
CASE
WHEN DEFAULTNUMBER IS NOT NULL THEN TO_CHAR(DEFAULTNUMBER)
WHEN DEFAULTDATE IS NOT NULL THEN TO_CHAR(DEFAULTDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
ELSE DEFAULTTEXT
END
AS COLUMNVALUE
FROM TESTER
WHERE tablename= 'table
and columnname ='field'

Comment: Is it `mdvs` or `mdva`? Are the columns of the `tester` table `def_number_value`, `def_text_value` and `def_date_value` as in your original question or have they now changed to `defaultnumber`, `defaulttext` and `defaultdate`?

Comment: The *not enough values* error is because you try to fetch three objects into `obj_mdva`. If you want to do it that way, you'll need to declare three of them and add them to the `select into`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object definition: (I removed the `l_` prefixes because we normally use `l_` for local variables, not type attributes):

```
create or replace type mdvs as object
( default_number    number
, default_text      varchar2(200)
, default_date      date
);

create table tester
( table_name        varchar2(128)
, column_name       varchar2(128)
, def_number_value  number
, def_text_value    varchar2(4000)
, def_date_value    date
, constraint tester_pk primary key (table_name, column_name) );
```

Test data:

```
insert all
    into tester(table_name, column_name, def_number_value)
    values ('T1', 'C1', 123)
    into tester(table_name, column_name, def_text_value)
    values ('T1', 'C2', 'Hello')
    into tester(table_name, column_name, def_date_value)
    values ('T1', 'C3', sysdate)
select * from dual;
```

Function:

```
create or replace function def_value
    ( f_table_name  in varchar2
    , f_column_name in varchar2 )
    return mdvs
is
    obj_mdvs mdvs;
begin
    begin
        select mdvs(def_number_value, def_text_value, def_date_value)
        into   obj_mdvs
        from   tester
        where  table_name = f_table_name
        and    column_name = f_column_name;
    exception
        when no_data_found then null;
    end;

    return
        case
            when obj_mdvs.default_number is not null then
                mdvs(obj_mdvs.default_number, null, null)
            when obj_mdvs.default_text is not null then
                mdvs(null, obj_mdvs.default_text, null)
            when obj_mdvs.default_date is not null then
                mdvs(null, null, obj_mdvs.default_date)
            else
                mdvs(0, null, null)
        end;
end def_value;
```

Note that we construct an `mdvs` object named `obj_mdvs` in SQL as part of the `select into` statement. (We could also have fetched the three values into separate variables and then constructed the object in a second step.) After that it will have values in its attributes `obj_mdvs.default_number` etc.

I wasn't sure what you wanted to use as the default to return when there is no matching row in the table, as `mdvs('NULL')` is not valid (unless you define a constructor function) because an `mdvs` object requires three values. You can adjust the `else` condition to suit your requirement.

PL/SQL syntax has no brackets around `if` conditions, because they are terminated by the `then` keyword.

Putting random bits of code in uppercase is quite popular in the industry and even used in the documentation examples, but PL/SQL isn't Cobol and it's not 1974 any more so you don't have to.

Test:

```
declare
    result mdvs;
begin
    result := def_value('T1', 'C2');

    dbms_output.put_line('result.default_number: '|| result.default_number);
    dbms_output.put_line('result.default_text:   '|| result.default_text);
    dbms_output.put_line('result.default_date:   '|| result.default_date);
end;
```

```
result.default_number:
result.default_text:   Hello
result.default_date:
```

Edit: thinking about it some more, it might be simpler to fetch the values into separate scalar variables, as we aren't really getting much value from the one created in the `select into`. Refactored version:

```
create or replace function def_value
    ( f_table_name  in varchar2
    , f_column_name in varchar2 )
    return mdvs
is
    default_mdvs     mdvs := mdvs(0, null, null);
    l_default_number default_mdvs.default_number%type;
    l_default_text   default_mdvs.default_text%type;
    l_default_date   default_mdvs.default_date%type;
begin
    begin
        select def_number_value, def_text_value, def_date_value
        into   l_default_number, l_default_text, l_default_date
        from   tester
        where  table_name = f_table_name
        and    column_name = f_column_name;
    exception
        when no_data_found then null;
    end;

    return
        case
            when l_default_number is not null then
                mdvs(l_default_number, null, null)
            when l_default_text is not null then
                mdvs(null, l_default_text, null)
            when l_default_date is not null then
                mdvs(null, null, l_default_date)
            else
                default_mdvs
        end;
end def_value;
```

Another Edit: If you want custom constructors so that you can define an object with just `mdvs(42)` for example, they might look something like this:

```
create or replace type mdvs as object
( default_number number
, default_text varchar2(200)
, default_date date
, constructor function mdvs (num number) return self as result 
, constructor function mdvs (txt varchar2) return self as result 
, constructor function mdvs (dt date) return self as result 
);
/

create or replace type body mdvs as
    constructor function mdvs (num number) return self as result 
    is
    begin
        self.default_number := num;
        return;
    end;

    constructor function mdvs (txt varchar2) return self as result 
    is
    begin
        self.default_text:= txt;
        return;
    end;

    constructor function mdvs (dt date) return self as result 
    is
    begin
        self.default_date := dt;
        return;
    end;
end;
/
```

**Another version of the function following comments:**

I have kept the original name for `mdvc` and the table columns `def_number_value`, `def_text_value` and `def_date_value`. Feel free to rename them in your environment.

Here is an example of creating three objects in the `select into` clause. It complicates the `select` but it simplifies the `return` clause. This version relies on the object constructors added above.

```
create or replace function defaulttest
    ( f_table_name  in varchar2
    , f_column_name in varchar2 )
    return mdvs
is
    obj_mdvs_number mdvs;
    obj_mdvs_text   mdvs;
    obj_mdvs_date   mdvs;
begin
    begin
        select mdvs(t.def_number_value), mdvs(t.def_text_value), mdvs(t.def_date_value)
        into   obj_mdvs_number, obj_mdvs_text, obj_mdvs_date
        from   tester t
        where  table_name = f_table_name
        and    column_name = f_column_name;
    exception
        when no_data_found then null;
    end;

    return coalesce(obj_mdvs_number, obj_mdvs_text, obj_mdvs_date);
end defaulttest;
```

**OK, last version I promise.** I don't think you need any object type, because you just want to return a plain scalar value (number, text or date). Forget about the object.

```
create or replace function defaulttest
    ( f_table_name  in varchar2
    , f_column_name in varchar2 )
    return varchar2
is
    l_numval tester.def_number_value%type;
    l_textval tester.def_text_value%type;
    t_dateval tester.def_text_value%type;
begin
    begin
        select t.def_number_value, t.def_text_value, t.def_date_value
        into   l_numval, l_textval, t_dateval
        from   tester t
        where  table_name = f_table_name
        and    column_name = f_column_name;
    exception
        when no_data_found then null;
    end;

    return coalesce(to_char(l_numval), l_textval, to_char(t_dateval));
end defaulttest;
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight.The code has to return only one value (defaultnumber or defaulttext or defaultdate) and ignore those with null values . so instead of  mdvs(l_default_number, null, null) can i fetch by passing only one parameter like  mdvs(l_default_number) . will this return the desired result ?

Comment: No, `mdvs` is an object type with three attributes, so its default constructor requires three corresponding arguments. You could define three custom constructors in the type body, one for each datatype.

Comment: Added examples of object constructors.

Comment: hi , how do i approach the function?. i have a code but doesnt seem to work . and facing errors. Code added.

Comment: Added a third version of the function, to illustrate multiple values in a `select into` clause.

Comment: hi, i am getting a wrong o/p. the desired result should be 4 for the given i/p parameters. instead it is SDPSGT.MDVA(4, NULL, NULL). I have attached the entire function.

Comment: The function returns an `mdva` object, which has three attributes. That is what your tool (SQL Developer, SQL\*Plus, PL/SQL Developer etc) is displaying - it's showing you the object. If you just want a number or text or date then I don't think you need an object type at all. The function will have to return the values as text though.

Comment: But in pl/SQL function, the return type needs to be specified. In our case, the return value can be either date or num or text. How can we create a return value without specifing in the object. For example. My normal sql code (mentioned in code section) return the correct value. How do I define in a function?

Comment: Well, your plain `select case ... end` version is returning a text value. Final version of the function added above that does that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use * in 'into' clause. Just specify variables there:

```sql
SELECT Def_NUMBER_Value,Def_TEXT_Value,Def_DATE_Value
INTO obj_mdvs.l_default_number ,obj_mdvs.l_default_text ,obj_mdvs.l_default_date
FROM    TESTER 
WHERE   Table_Name=f_table_Name
AND     Column_Name=f_column_Name;
```